# freeing an array of lists

Tags: c, arrays

I got a memory leak in my program, and I can't understand why. I got a 4 size array of linked lists, and valgrind says there is a memory leak.

Here is my struct:

```
struct node {
    achievementMen100m player;
    char* playerName;
    Men100mAchievement playerAchiInRound;
    char*currentRound;
    struct node *head;
    struct node *next;
} node, *Node;
```

Here is my allocation in the create function:

```
for(int i=0; i<4;i++){
    OG->games->head->phases[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct node)); //VALGRIND SAYS MEMORY ALLOCATED HERE NOT FREED!//
    OG->games->head->phases[i]->head=NULL;
    OG->games->head->phases[i]->next=NULL;
    OG->games->head->phases[i]->playerAchiInRound = 0;
}
```

Here is my `free-list` function:

```
void listDestroy(struct node * list) {
struct node * currentPlayer = list;
struct node * temp;
while (currentPlayer != NULL) {
    temp = currentPlayer;
    currentPlayer=currentPlayer->next;
    free(temp->playerName);
    free(temp);
}
list = NULL;
free(list);

}
```

And this is the free function of the ADT:

```
void olympicGamesDestroy(OlympicGames OG) {
if (OG == NULL) {
    return;
}
if (OG->games == NULL) {
    free(OG);
    return;
}
if (OG->games->head == NULL) {
    free(OG->games);
    free(OG);
    return;
}
for (int i=0; i<4;i++) {
    listDestroy(OG->games->head->phases[i]->head);
}
free(OG->games->next);
free(OG->games->head);
free(OG->games);
free(OG);
}
```

***update***
here is my entire .h file

```
typedef struct men100 {
Men100mAchievement olympicMinimum;
Men100mAchievement olympicSkipPre;
char* roundNames[4];
struct node* phases[4];
} men100, *Men100;

typedef struct gameList {
int name;
men100* head;
struct gameList *next;
} gameList, *GameList;


typedef struct olympicGames {
GameList games;
int numOfGames;
} olympicGames, *OlympicGames;
```

Comment: Did you check how often `free(temp)` is called in the while-loop?

Comment: If you like our community so much (compare with edit history), please have a look at [ask] and provide a direct [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Your `void olympicGamesDestroy(OlympicGames OG)` looks strange!

You are allocating at `OG->games->head->phases[i]`.

So, where are you `free`ing them? You are only working on `OG->games->head->phases[i]->head` and not on `OG->games->head->phases[i]`.

Show the actual `OlympicGames` data structure.

**UPDATE**:

I don't have much time to verify the whole code:

But you can try the following:

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    listDestroy(OG->games->head->phases[i]->head);
    free(OG->games->head->phases[i]); // you need this
}
```

Comment: @EliorKanfi: See the third para in my answer and reply to me.

Comment: when i'm sending to listDestroy  OG->games->head->phases[i] then i get a runtime error "pointer being freed was not allocated"

Comment: @EliorKanfi: that's wrong! you only need to free the `phases[i]`s and not what is allocated inside.

Comment: @EliorKanfi: show the `main` function. Also, edit your code sections in the question to a single verifiable code.

Comment: the main function is in a different .c file that has few functions with our homework. i dont think it could do much help here